# issues with "jumping" using anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

There seems to be a few subjects on anchor tags but I am missing something on how to use Javascript to use an anchor tag without the jump. So my page is loaded and I have a div that holds 2 charts ( 1 hidden ) and has 2 tabs on the side. I'd like to use those tabs to interchange the charts without having the page jump down to the anchor tag. I have my code below but not sure what I need to switch to make it work.

HTML:

```
  <div style="width:550px; height:200px; padding:0px; border:0px; margin:0px;">
  <div id="chartContainer" style="width:500px; height:200px; overflow:hidden; position:relative; float:left;">Chart...</div>
    <div style="width:25px; height:200px; float:left; position:relative; padding-top:11px;">
    <div id="tabs1_div"  style=" position:relative; float:left; padding-bottom:10px;"><a href="#" onClick="chartRender('Tab1');" ><img src="images/labortab.png" /></a></div>
    <div id="tabs2_div"  style=" position:relative; float:left;"><a href="#" onClick="chartRender('Tab2');" ><img src="images/odctab.png" /></a></div> 
  </div>    
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript');
var myChart = new FusionCharts("Charts/Column2D.swf", "myChartId", "100%", "100%", "0");
myChart.setXMLUrl("Data/Data.xml");
myChart.render("chartContainer");

var myChart1 = new FusionCharts("Charts/Column3D.swf", "myChartId1", "100%", "100%", "0");
myChart1.setXMLUrl("Data/Data.xml");
//myChart1.render("chartContainer");

function chartRender(arg) {
    if (arg == "Tab1") {
        myChart.render("chartContainer");
    }
    else if (arg == "Tab2") {
        myChart1.render("chartContainer");
    }

}
// -->  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `return:false` to your chartRender function.

```
function chartRender(arg) {
    if (arg == "Tab1") {
        myChart.render("chartContainer");
    }
    else if (arg == "Tab2") {
        myChart1.render("chartContainer");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Your links are following the href attribute (`#`) which defaults to the top of the page. By returning false you cancel that behavior. Be sure to also modify the call to the function like `onClick="return chartRender('Tab2');"`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FZWtx/)**

Answer (score 1):

Using `return false;` - while it may prevent the jumping, it is a little overkill.  It's important that you understand what happens when you click something - 2 things happen:

1. A "click" event is fired on the element that you clicked.  This
   click event bubbles up the DOM Tree (HTML) until it reaches the root
   element (the HTML tag or Window).
2. If the item you clicked was a hyperlink and has an `href`, the
   browser is going to take some sort of action to execute the
   hyperlink - in your case a hash tag, which results in the jumping.

The event bubbling described in #1 is important, as you may have some sort of analytics system which puts a catch-all event listener on the BODY tag.  You might also have other plugins on the page which perform some other action whenever a hyperlink is clicked.  The point is, you never know what else may or may not need that click event in the future - so it doesn't hurt to let the "click" event bubble up the DOM.  By using `return false;` you are preventing anything else from knowing that a click event happened.

The main thing you want to do is prevent the default behavior of the hyperlink.  To do this, you can call `preventDefault()` in the event handler:

```
var hyperlink = document.getElementById("my-hyperlink");
hyperlink.onclick = function(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default behavior of the browser
}
```

You could also do the following, which is essentially the same thing as `return false;`, but is more descript and "proper" in terms of programming with JavaScript:

```
var hyperlink = document.getElementById("my-hyperlink");
hyperlink.onclick = function(ev) {
   ev.stopPropagation(); // Stop the event bubbling
   ev.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default behavior of the browser
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function you're calling on `<a>` click, add a `return false;` at the end, this will prevent it from jumping.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `onClick` in your dom, I would do this in your javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".chartRenderer").click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //this will prevent the "jump"
        var arg = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
        if (arg == "tabs1_div") {
            myChart.render("chartContainer");
        }
        else if (arg == "tabs2_div") {
            myChart1.render("chartContainer");
        }
    });
});
```

This will require you to add a `class` of `chartRenderer` on your anchors.